# How to stop LGTM from wrapping qmake

Tags: github, cmake, build-automation, qmake, semmle-ql

The automated code review service [LGTM](https://lgtm.com/) uses ["wrapper scripts around the popular build tools like pkg-config, CMake, and qmake"](https://blog.semmle.com/cplusplus-projects-lgtm/) to detect missing files during the build process and to install the corresponding packages automatically.

My project uses `CMake`, but to get some path from Qt, I need `qmake` in one place:

```
get_target_property(qt5_qmake Qt5::qmake IMPORTED_LOCATION)
execute_process(COMMAND ${qt5_qmake} -query QT_INSTALL_TRANSLATIONS OUTPUT_VARIABLE QT_QM_PATH)
```

These lines work fine everywhere I've tested them, except in the LGTM environment.
In the LGTM environment, the desired information is not put into the `QT_QM_PATH`, but printed (it's visible in the build log).

I strongly suspect the wrapper causing that since other commands work as expected.

**Question**: How can I stop LGTM from wrapping `qmake` or how can I trick `cmake` to capture the output of the wrapped `qmake`?